# How do I use scale_colour_manual?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

Does anyone know any bugs/tricks when using scale_colour_manual to set colors to predefined settings based on HEX color codes contained in your data frame?

I have been trying to to use the following code to pull predefined color codes from my data frame.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour=company)) 
p <- p + geom_point()
p <- p + scale_colour_manual(breaks=df$company, values = df$col)
p
```

However, for some reason when the plot is rendered the colors that are in the data (i.e. values=df$col) are not ploted.

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Below is my ggplot structure/data:

```
structure(list(data = structure(list(x = c(119, 34, 34, 46, 86, 
70, 61, 71, 84, 30, 84, 85, 3, 16, 5, 167, 72, 85, 5, 44, 85, 
63, 15, 86, 148, 83, 105, 11, 11, 98, 169, 14, 11, 28, 98, 52, 
52, 52, 90, 11, 176, 94, 94, 52, 9, 176, 148, 9, 105, 121, 98, 
2, 28, 9, 148, 43, 148, 170, 146, 40, 61, 40, 98, 9, 5, 3, 45, 
46, 6, 128, 123, 39, 45, 2, 19), y = c(1195.26050420168, 4005.55882352941, 
4102.94117647059, 3670.23913043478, 7705.47674418605, 7373.34285714286, 
4745.40983606557, 5158.43661971831, 7686.20238095238, 7301.43333333333, 
7309.02380952381, 7336.03529411765, 3475.33333333333, 5467.4375, 
5117, 3861.70658682635, 8940.34722222222, 7317.41176470588, 4182.8, 
6301.90909090909, 7272.83529411765, 4670.47619047619, 6489.53333333333, 
7452.24418604651, 7762.66891891892, 7768.5421686747, 5560.00504761905, 
9360.71454545455, 10984.6854545455, 6677.94989795918, 5029.19917159763, 
17012.2242857143, 8613.21818181818, 5632.53571428571, 7572.70642857143, 
12890, 8876.30557692308, 12993.5084615385, 364.15, 10914, 13005.2405113636, 
11607.0582978723, 2946.36404255319, 14684.7426923077, 1783.90444444444, 
11400.6083522727, 4940.83817567568, 1609.11111111111, 7636.22476190476, 
318.785123966942, 8798.37673469388, 459.3, 8735.70928571429, 
1616.36222222222, 6279.4397972973, 1564.2711627907, 5410.90743243243, 
2569.18029411765, 6825.9702739726, 22469.3135, 6288.34426229508, 
22726.2695, 11580.1029591837, 1733.73333333333, 2528.8, 1161.66666666667, 
4126.06666666667, 4024.13043478261, 3336.5, 2928.9375, 2675.44715447154, 
4249.79487179487, 7005.95555555556, 1601, 3982.26315789474), 
    company = c("chief", "chief", "chief", "chief", "CHK", "CHK", 
    "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", 
    "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", 
    "CHK", "CHK", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", 
    "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", 
    "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", 
    "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", 
    "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "CRZO", "CRZO", "CRZO", "CRZO", 
    "CRZO", "Other", "Other", "WPX", "WPX", "WPX", "WPX"), col = c("#000000", 
    "#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
    "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
    "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "darkgreen", 
    "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "#000000", 
    "#000000", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange")), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "company", "col"), row.names = c(NA, -75L), class = "data.frame"), 
    layers = list(<environment>), scales = <S4 object of class structure("Scales", package = "ggplot2")>, 
    mapping = structure(list(x = quote(x), y = quote(y), colour = quote(company)), .Names = c("x", 
    "y", "colour"), class = "uneval"), options = structure(list(
        labels = structure(list(x = "x", y = "y", colour = "company"), .Names = c("x", 
        "y", "colour"))), .Names = "labels"), coordinates = structure(list(
        limits = structure(list(x = NULL, y = NULL), .Names = c("x", 
        "y")), wise = FALSE), .Names = c("limits", "wise"), class = c("cartesian", 
    "coord")), facet = structure(list(shrink = TRUE), .Names = "shrink", class = c("null", 
    "facet")), plot_env = <environment>), .Names = c("data", 
"layers", "scales", "mapping", "options", "coordinates", "facet", 
"plot_env"), class = "ggplot")
```

Comment: maybe you want `scale_colour_identity()` and `aes(colour=col)`

Comment: You misunderstood my previous answer (or perhaps I didn't explain myself). You pass _unique_ breaks and colors to `scale_colour_manual`, not vectors from your entire dataframe (that's how base graphics works, not ggplot).

Comment: And in any case, using @baptiste's method you still have to specify the (unique) breaks and labels to make the legend appear anyway.

Comment: Ah..so if I...brk=unique(df$company)
col=unique(df$col)
p <- p + scale_colour_manual(breaks=brk, values = col)
p...gets better but still need to find a way to keep breaks and colors alined because now "chief" is black instead of other.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Combining the comments from baptiste and joran, either of these work, depending on what you want.

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(119, 34, 34, 46, 86, 
70, 61, 71, 84, 30, 84, 85, 3, 16, 5, 167, 72, 85, 5, 44, 85, 
63, 15, 86, 148, 83, 105, 11, 11, 98, 169, 14, 11, 28, 98, 52, 
52, 52, 90, 11, 176, 94, 94, 52, 9, 176, 148, 9, 105, 121, 98, 
2, 28, 9, 148, 43, 148, 170, 146, 40, 61, 40, 98, 9, 5, 3, 45, 
46, 6, 128, 123, 39, 45, 2, 19), y = c(1195.26050420168, 4005.55882352941, 
4102.94117647059, 3670.23913043478, 7705.47674418605, 7373.34285714286, 
4745.40983606557, 5158.43661971831, 7686.20238095238, 7301.43333333333, 
7309.02380952381, 7336.03529411765, 3475.33333333333, 5467.4375, 
5117, 3861.70658682635, 8940.34722222222, 7317.41176470588, 4182.8, 
6301.90909090909, 7272.83529411765, 4670.47619047619, 6489.53333333333, 
7452.24418604651, 7762.66891891892, 7768.5421686747, 5560.00504761905, 
9360.71454545455, 10984.6854545455, 6677.94989795918, 5029.19917159763, 
17012.2242857143, 8613.21818181818, 5632.53571428571, 7572.70642857143, 
12890, 8876.30557692308, 12993.5084615385, 364.15, 10914, 13005.2405113636, 
11607.0582978723, 2946.36404255319, 14684.7426923077, 1783.90444444444, 
11400.6083522727, 4940.83817567568, 1609.11111111111, 7636.22476190476, 
318.785123966942, 8798.37673469388, 459.3, 8735.70928571429, 
1616.36222222222, 6279.4397972973, 1564.2711627907, 5410.90743243243, 
2569.18029411765, 6825.9702739726, 22469.3135, 6288.34426229508, 
22726.2695, 11580.1029591837, 1733.73333333333, 2528.8, 1161.66666666667, 
4126.06666666667, 4024.13043478261, 3336.5, 2928.9375, 2675.44715447154, 
4249.79487179487, 7005.95555555556, 1601, 3982.26315789474), 
    company = c("chief", "chief", "chief", "chief", "CHK", "CHK", 
    "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", 
    "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", "CHK", 
    "CHK", "CHK", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", 
    "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", 
    "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", 
    "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", 
    "COG", "COG", "COG", "COG", "CRZO", "CRZO", "CRZO", "CRZO", 
    "CRZO", "Other", "Other", "WPX", "WPX", "WPX", "WPX"), col = c("#000000", 
    "#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
    "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
    "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "darkgreen", 
    "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "darkgreen", "#000000", 
    "#000000", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange")), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "company", "col"), row.names = c(NA, -75L), class = "data.frame")
```

If you want to color points by the given color, use `scale_colour_identity()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour=col)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_identity()
```

[image]

There is no scale, because the color itself is the scale.

If you want to map certain values of company to certain colors, and those colors just happen to be along in the original data set, then you need to pull that mapping out and use the manual scale.

```
colmapping <- unique(df[c("company","col")])

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour=company)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(breaks=colmapping$company, values=colmapping$col)
```

[image]